# Cannot expand server is SSMS

Tags: sql-server, database, object, ssms

I've come across a bit of a weird issue today that I am stuck on what is wrong and how to fix it.

When I log in to SSMS, I can see my server and it connects OK, but there is nothing underneath the server level (ie. Databases, Objects, etc) and there is no +/- expansion box.

All of the databases on the server are online according to sys.databases, all have is_read_only set to 0 and all have MULTI_USER access.

I can open a query window directly on the server and then perform statements on the database by using the full path or a USE statement, but I can't for the life of me get the server expand/collapse to work.

I've tried restarting SSMS, logging off from direct access to the server and also accessing SSMS on another client connected to the server, but the same thing happens.  This leads me to believe there is either an issue with my profile or with the server config itself?

Has anyone else come across this issue?

**USING**

- SSMS 10.50.2500.0
- Accessing SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Which ssms client do you use? And are you connecting to SQL Server 2000?

Comment: SSMS - 10.50.2500.0
SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the interface?

Comment: Not sure what happened, but this eventually resulted in all users getting timeouts.
Were reluctant to stop and restart during the day, but this has resolved the issue, even though it gave a timeout message on stopping the SQL service as well, but it had successfully stopped the service somehow.
None the wiser as to what actually caused the problem though.
Thanks folks!